# Flexlider - Automatic sliding

Tags: flexslider

I've got the Flexslider "plugged in" to me website, although there appears to be a generic programming problem with it (I am a complete coding novice). When playing a video, the automatic scrolling does not stop so it continues to show other videos when it is playing, this only stops when you specifically press the "thumbnail" link at the bottom.

Has anyone encountered this before and managed to see if this can be stopped?

Comment: Sure it is “possible”, but how exactly will depend on how he video is embedded. http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ has two examples for that already btw.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you should disable the auto sliding in the slider initialization. You can do that like this:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    slideshow: false
});
```